# LDAP bind with TLS: Start TLS request accepted but not working

Tags: ssl, ldap

I am trying in vain to do a LDAP bind from a linux based device to a ldap server with TLS.
The server supports both simple authentication and TLS authentication.
First, I successfully bind without TLS with the following ldapsearch command:

```
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=lab,dc=local"  \
-H ldap://[SERVER.IP.ADDRESS] \
-D "uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=lab,dc=local" \
-W "uid=myuser"
```

It prompts to the user password, and successfully authenticate the user.
When I try to bind using TLS  with the following:

```
LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never ldapsearch \
-x -ZZ -b "dc=lab,dc=local" \
-H ldap://[SERVER.IP.ADDRESS] \
-D "uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=lab,dc=local" \
-W "uid=myuser" cn uid
```

I'm not prompted for the password, so I added a `-d 1` option for having more debug messages.
In this case, I have the following output:

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://nodo-1.labsecurity.local)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://nodo-1.labsecurity.local:389/??base)
ldap_extended_operation_s
ldap_extended_operation
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP nodo-1.labsecurity.local:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.5.214:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect: 
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_flush2: 31 bytes to sd 3
ldap_result ld 0x1005c038 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x1005c038 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x1005c038 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x1005c038 Connections:
* host: nodo-1.labsecurity.local  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Thu Jan  1 00:49:07 1970


** ld 0x1005c038 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x1005c038 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x1005c038 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x1005c038 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x1005c038 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x1005c038 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x1005c038 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 95 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x1005c038 msgid 1 message type extended-result
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x1005c038 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x1005c038 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x1005c038 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <Start TLS request accepted.Server willing to negotiate SSL.>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_extended_result
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (a) ber:
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (x) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
```

It seems the connection is established, but at a certain point it stops and doesn't go on anymore.
Note that I used the LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never which shhould imply the CA certificate is not required.
Can anyone help me to better understand why LDAP bind with TLS is not working?
Thank you.

Comment: LDAP with TLS is exposed on a different port - 636 by default, so the URL needs to be updated as `ldaps://[SERVER.IP.ADDRESS]:636`. Can you try this and see if it connects?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that my ldap server uses START TLS mechanism, so, as far as I know, it uses the ordinary port (389).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I would suggest reviewing the server-side configuration for TLS. Perhaps the server is encountering an issue when loading the certificate before presenting it to the client.

Comment: Here are a few things you could try: 1) "openssl s_client -connect <insert-ldap-server-ip>:389 -starttls ldap -showcerts", and see if your LDAP server sends a certificate; 2) If your ldapsearch is using GNU TLS, then you can try adding "GNUTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL=9" as an environment variable in front of your ldapsearch, and this might provide some useful info; 3) Removing "LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never" from your command and see if the debug output provides more information.

Comment: Is LDAP TLS working for other clients with that same server?  Knowing this would help us narrow down the possible causes.